# display: -webkit-box; sometimes crashes my iPad

Tags: ipad, crash, flexbox

Do you have any ideas why my websites keep crashing on single post template? It is powered by Wordpress. The problem appears only on iPad (I've tested two iPad 2's).

http://luzlol.me

How do I diagnose such things? Thanks.

**update:** I figured out the reason.

```
display: -webkit-box;
```

crashes my iPad on single post template (like http://luzlol.me/bittorrent-sync/ this one), don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deativate W3TC and use your dev tools console to fix your jQuery errors. Use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) with Firefox, or use the developer tools in [Chrome](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/overview) or [Safari](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/2SafariDeveloperTools/SafariDeveloperTools.html) or [IE.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg589507(v=vs.85).aspx)

Use the http://validator.w3.org/ to check your html and css.

Comment: I've fixed javascript error, thanks. Do you suggest permanently deactivate W3TC? Oo I mean maybe I should tweak the settings. 

By the way, why does this crash appear only in single post? can't figure out...

Comment: Mkay, I don't have validation errors right now (except for related posts plugin css, but I've tried to deactivate it) and I've tried to deactivate W3TC. Nothing worked, all the pages, which are generated by single.php template crash the iPad =(

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a webkit bug, nothing to do here. Thanks. I hope this one will be fixed soon.